# Is it possible to migrate Lightning App created through lightning manager using change set

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

Is it possible to migrate Lightning App created through lightning manager using change set.

I checked in apps the lightning apps are not shown.